# How to fill an array with the information of a txt file and then using that array?

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

sorry all if this question was done before but couldn't find it and similar examples didn't work.

I want to put the information of a txt file in an array on VBA. And then use that array to fill different strings of the code. Can you help me? Right now I can't get read the file and fill the array.

The idea is this:
Document with number of client, address, etc for each line
VBA reads the txt and fills an array, each position is a line of the txt.
I use the array to fill the template:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "CLIENTENumber"
        .Replacement.Text = ARRAY[Positionwithclient]
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Thank you!!

For extra info, the information on txt is arranged the following way:

```
565656
Peter
(etc)
```

Being the first the client number, the second the name, etc. Then I will replace the "CLIENTNumber" in the word document with the 565656, for example. The replacement code is above and works well.

Comment: You need to tell us how the data in the textfile are arranged and how they relate to what's in the Word document.

Comment: Hello @macropod, I edited the main question with the way the textfile is arranged.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim SrcDoc As Document, RList, i As Long
Const FList As String = "CLIENTNumber,CLIENTName"
'Load the strings from the reference file into a text string to be used as an array.
Set SrcDoc = Documents.Open("Drive:\FilePath\DataList.txt", ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
With SrcDoc
  RList = .Range.Text
  .Close False
End With
Set SrcDoc = Nothing
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .MatchWholeWord = True
  .MatchCase = True
  For i = 0 To UBound(Split(FList, ","))
    .Text = Split(FList, vbCr)(i)
    .Replacement.Text = Split(RList, vbCr)(i)
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Simply supply all the items for the FList string, with nothing but a comma separating them and in the order in which they appear in the text file, and the full path & name to the text file where indicated.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your kind help! I will work with this information! :)